# Django get the latest 3 results in a filter set

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a query that does the following:

- List results only from the last 4 months - Check
- Remove results where the best time is 0 - Check
- List unique clubs and teams - Check
- Get the best times from the set - Check
- Put the clubs and teams in order - Check

The only condition i need now is:

- If a club or team lists more than 3 times (before getting the best times), take the 3 most recent results only.

-

```
place = Placing.objects \
.filter(event_date__gte=start_date) \
.filter(best_time__gt=0) \
.values_list('club_name','team_name') \
.annotate(Min('best_time')) \
.order_by('club_name','team_name')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to `LIMIT` your query (through Python slicing), which means you are also going to have to query for each team separately as I don't think a `LIMIT` clause can be expressed multiple times - on the plus side, you will then be able to `aggregate(Min('best_time'))`!

If you need to have a `QuerySet` of `Placing` objects, you will be able to build one concatenating your results with the `|` operator.

Also, what's the difference between Club and Team?

edit: maybe something like this

```
from django.db.models import Min
besties = {}
for team in teams:
    besties[team] = Placing.objects \
    .filter(event_date__gte=start_date, best_time__gt=0).order_by(-event_date) \
    .filter(team_name=team)[:3].aggregate(Min('best_time'))['best_time__min']
```

Comment: Thanks mccc, a club has multiple teams, a team has multiple placings (because they go to multiple events).

Comment: Struggling with the syntax for this one, how would i implement this? Simply adding [:3] between the values_list and aggregate will generate an error.